# In the context of cooking, what is the difference between "flipper" and "spatula"?

Tags: differences, nouns, word-usage, dialects, terminology

I'm genuinely confused about this because at first I thought a spatula was a cooking tool resembling a flat pallet attached at an angle to the handle that could be used for activities such as flipping eggs.

Then I noticed in stores what I thought was a spatula was labelled "[flipper](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-U32ZS4VNt7k/TWRk5Xoyj8I/AAAAAAAABLs/NHybR5jFkp0/s1600/DSC_0581.JPG)" and a "[spatula](http://www.shopkitchenaid.com/digitalassets/5063632/Standalone_1175X1290.jpg)" was something else that was flat in profile as having the handle parallel with the head of the device.

Now people are telling me there's no such thing as a flipper in terms of a cooking device.

I believe the terminology may vary by region. What is a flipper and what is  a spatula and in which parts of the world do the definitions apply? For completeness sake, do some people call one of the devices a "turner" (I've never heard this before @choster used it)?

Comment: Surely you mean a *turner*, not a *flipper*. *Flipper* is a dolphin.

Comment: @choster Negative. I have others comment the same and I do not mistakenly use the word *flipper* instead of *turner*.

Comment: I usually call those a *flipper* myself. I think *turner* and *spatula* are more common/proper names for the same thing. See my answer below.

Comment: [Spatula City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XbCWmY0eqY)

Comment: There's some evidence for “pancake flipper” meaning a turner in Google Books, but it’s only about 1/10th as common as “pancake turner,” so it’s not surprising that many people haven’t heard it before. I updated my answer with a link to the Ngram.

Comment: For example, see [the Pancake Flipper category on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/pancake-flipper).

Comment: I wonder if this has ever been used in the _What's the difference_ segment on the _Says You_ radio program?

Comment: Flipper is a dolphin.

Comment: Sigh!!  If your mother called it a flipper, you call it a flipper.  If your mother called it a spatula, you call it a spatula.  And if you walk into a kitchen store at the local mall your head will explode from all the different terms used, in an attempt to "distinguish" one product from another.

Answer (score 13):

A [spatula](http://i.word.com/idictionary/spatula) in cooking is a flat object often made of rubber or metal meant to spread, mix or lift food.

A [flipper or turner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pancake+turner) are flat objects usually made of metal or plastic designed to slide under a piece of food in a pan or on a grill.  The broad flat blade facilities easy turning of the food.  (Flipper sounds more like a colloquialism for turner to me. Also *Pancake Flipper* or *Burger Flipper* is frequently used to refer to the *person* doing the flipping - that is a short-order cook …)

[image: Pancake Turner]

Rubber (or silicone) spatulas with handles are also called scrapers.  (With no handle they are called bowl scrapers.)

Small metal spatulas are often called icing knives.

[image: Rubber spatulas] [image: Icing Knife]

A *spatula* can refer to any tool with a small flat blade.  It is [derived directly from Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=spatula&allowed_in_frame=0), having come to English in the 1520s as a medical instrument.  *Spatula* the diminutive of the Latin *spatha* meaning a "broad, flat tool or weapon," from Greek *spathe* "broad flat blade (used by weavers)".

**Update**
Based upon my review of multiple cook's tool resellers (Williams-Sonoma, etc.) it seems that turners are frequently called spatulas. And, rubber scrapers are also called spatulas.  But, a rubber scraper cannot be called a turner, and vice-versa.

Comment: I've seen that distinction before too – but also the reverse. For example, Wikipedia says that your “spatula” is properly called a *scraper,* while the “turner” is properly a *spatula.* It seems that they're all just different varieties of spatula.

Comment: @Bradd that is true. A spatula always has a flat blade like object on its end. But, most chefs distinguish the two as above.

Comment: I'm not convinced – for example, another answer insists that a real chef would only use spatula for a palette knife. I think people have strong opinions on spatulas but there's no clear consensus.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Now that I'm not on my phone, I gave a better answer.

Comment: Do you have something to back up the use of *flipper*? The link you gave only defines "turner" or "food turner". I've only ever heard flipper used to mean fin.

Comment: @starplusplus it's a term I've heard but don't use. Pancake flipper vs turner.

Comment: This answer still implies that a spatula is properly a scraper rather than a turner. While normally I'd take your word for that, it's sort of at the heart of the question here, and other sources disagree. Please provide evidence for the claim, so that this is not unsourced prescriptivism.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I think I've nailed it down for you.

Comment: That's an improvement but the last paragraph sounds weird.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Better?

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, if you search for images of *[spatula](https://www.google.com/search?q=spatula&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=KNk9U-ioBsvPsASfroAY&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=643)* in Google, about half of the images are for the device used to turn over pancakes, and half are for the device used to scrape food from a jar.

A similar search for *turner* results in images for the artist. However, a sidebar offers images for *[kitchen turner](https://www.google.com/search?q=turner&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=VNs9U6XhLLPLsQTvz4CoDg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=643#q=kitchen%20turner&revid=1773025074&tbm=isch&imgdii=_)* which leads to pictures of the pancake reorienting machine.  Delving into these images offer a variety of terms, such as *slotted turner, griddle turner* and *pancake turner*.

A search for *[turner](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=turner)* on the Amazon shopping site offers a range of griddle or pan related utensils. A similar search for *[spatula](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=spatula&rh=i%3aaps,k%3aspatula)* yields the mixed bag.

A search in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=flipper&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ht09U_b7FsKzsAS9joHgBg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=643) images or [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=flipper&rh=i%3aaps,k%3aflipper) for *flipper* yields dolphins (the mammals not the fish).

In sum, if the interweb is to be believed, *spatula* means either an inversion device or a scraping device, and *turner* means an inversion device.

Comment: Well that settles it. The latter is a spatula and the former is a pancake reorienting machine!

Comment: although I might go for *device* rather than *machine*

Comment: @Jim The lever and the wedge are both classified as machines... So I guess if you didn't mind explaining that every time someone asked, you could go with "machine."

Comment: A glorified Google search does not an answer make.

Comment: @StevenPenny- I think quite often it actually does.

Comment: Kitchen flipper: https://www.google.com/search?q=kitchen+flipper&tbm=isch

Comment: @DavidMulder Interseting. An Amazon search for that term also shows a few inversion utensils, but all of the labels call them *turners*.

Comment: Google essentially gives you the most common usage among people whose age is probably below average and social status probably above -- fine by me, but worth pointing out.

Comment: @PatrickT What I really would like to know (since I don't qualify) is what professional cooks call them.

Comment: @bib, I don't know any professional cooks to ask, unfortunately... In French, they call them «spatule à retourner» (according to a website that sells utensils to professionals), which essentially means «flipping spatula»  :-)

Answer (score 5):

The English usage of these terms and the kitchen's (more exacting) usage of these terms differ, slightly. You may get a more nuanced response on our sister site, http://cooking.stackexchange.com.

Some pictures may help. Please see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18682. In my dialect of AE, I had never heard of "flipper," but only a "pancake turner" or a "spatula." (Of course, they were used for turning more than pancakes.)

In the kitchen's more specific usage, the spatula is the long, thin blade used to spread icing on a cake. (Also to pry open watch backs.) See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22277.

In my AE usage, a pancake turner is called a spatula. And many companies have marketed flexible scrapers as spatulas as well.

Comment: Same here (New England), we call a pancake turner a spatula. I'd never heard *flipper*, but I'd know what it meant. We usually use *scraper* or *rubber spatula* to describe the other thing, and *frosting knife* to describe the watch back opener.

Comment: I held up a rubber scraper and a pancake turner and asked my teenager daughter (raised in the South to Northern parents) to name them. She called them a *spatula* and a *flipper*. I was quite surprised that word she proffered for the latter was one that I had not heard before this question was posed.

Answer (score 4):

**[Spatula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatula)** refers to several kitchen* tools used for lifting, spreading, scraping, and sometimes mixing. They all have [broad, flat, flexible blades](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=spatula), for which they are named. There are three major varieties:

- **[Turners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_slice_%28kitchen_utensil%29)** are used to lift and flip food like pancakes and filets. Some people call these *[flippers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pancake%20turner,%20pancake%20flipper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,pancake%20turner;,c0;.t1;,pancake%20flipper;,c0),* but it’s comparatively rare and not well documented. *Fish slice* is the British English name for a common kind of turner.
- **[Palette knives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frosting_spatula)** are used for spreading, such as frosting a cake. They’re also called *frosting spatulas* and (in Canada) *levelers.*
- **[Scrapers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scraper_%28kitchen%29)** are used to empty containers and clean surfaces. Some scrapers are also useful for mixing, folding, or stirring ingredients.

For some reason, spatulas inspire a kind of nomenclature prescriptivism. Some people insist that *spatula* properly refers only to scrapers, and that it’s an error to use the word for a turner. Other people insist that palette knives are the only true spatulas. One thing is certain:

You can call any of these things a spatula, and everyone will know what you mean, but a bunch of people will think you are calling it the wrong thing.

---

<sup>* and laboratory</sup>

Comment: No criticism, Bradd, but I wanted to let the question mellow for a day before upvoting any answer. I have not heard "fish slices." I am not the baking authority, but I thought of the spatula for spreading the base layer of frosting or fondant and the palette knives for applying the decorative aspects.

Comment: Expanded my answer a bit, and touched on the “one true spatula” debate.

Answer (score 1):

In this part of Canada (southern Ontario), pass me the flipper will get you a turner, pass me the spatula will get you a turner or a scraper, and pass the scraper will get you a rubber spatula.  No consensus.  Spatula seems to mean anything you want but in my kitchen a turner is called a flipper and a scraper is called a spatula.  Don't know why - ask my mom.

Answer (score 0):

In Australia, a *spatula* is this image below:

[image]

While a "flipper" or "turner" (in school I was taught to call it an egg flip, but can be used for other things) is the below picture:

[image]

Hope this helps from an Australian point of view.